# Download an email attachment file to a custom folder in Android external storage

Tags: java, android, email-attachments, android-external-storage

In my app I've created a parent folder in external storage with child folders inside named after the current user's **userId**.

How would I programmatically direct email file attachment downloads to one of these folders? Is there a way to add these folders to the Share Sheet?

I want to be able to open an email with an attachment in an email client app and download the attachment directly to one of these folders. The only way I can see how to do it now would download the file to downloads and then copy the file to my custom folder.

But, is there any way I can directly download the attachment file to my custom folder?

Comment: Your question was closed lacking enough info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63057976/how-would-i-direct-an-import-of-an-email-file-attachment-to-a-custom-external-st

Comment: @blackapps I don't understand how it's 'lacking enough info' - my question couldn't be clearer.

Comment: Well ask the moderators.